# sed/awk: modify source file?

Tags: sed, awk

I'm trying to script some changes I need to make to a couple of config files. It's worth mentioning that I'm an expert with neither sed nor awk, though I'm far better with sed.

Right now, I'm doing:

```
sed '/setting.name/c setting.name: newvalue' </etc/foo.conf >tmpfile.tmp && mv tmpfile.tmp /etc/foo.conf
```

But surely there's a better way? Perhaps with awk?

Comment: `man sed` tells me that you should use the `-i, --in-place` switch (if available in your version of sed. For awk there does not seem to be such an option...maybe you want to write a short script to do it.

Comment: Argh. RTFM, Joe!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way:

```
 sed -i.bak 's/Old Info/New Info/' file.cfg
```

That edits the file in place, but saves the original as 'name.cfg.bak'.

If you know all the things to change, then you'd probably want a script to do it like:

```
 sed -i.bak -e 's/first setting/new first/' -e 's/next setting/new next/' -e 's/etc/new etc/' file.cfg
```